# Just wondering what is Exactly Wrong With My Code C programming

Tags: c

i have no idea what is wrong with my code i am using visual studio and it says that i dont have an identifier and im not 100% sure what it means im basically having to write a new function for pow i didnt really understand it to much but if someone could look at my code it would be really helpful thank you

```
// Programmer:     Your Name
// Date:           Date
// Program Name:   The name of the program
// Chapter:        Chapter # - Chapter name
// Description:    2 complete English sentences describing what the  program does,
//                 algorithm used, etc.
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS // Disable warnings (and errors) when using non-secure versions of printf, scanf, strcpy, etc.
#include <stdio.h> // Needed for working with printf and scanf
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    // Constant and Variable Declarations
    double power(double num, int power) {
        double result = 1;
        if (power > 0) {
            int i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < power; i++) {
                result *= num;
            }
            return result;
        }
        else {
            if (power < 0) {
                power *= -1;
                int i = 0;
                for (i = 0; i < power; i++) {
                    result *= num;
                }
            }
            return 1 / result;
        }
    }
    int main(void)
    {
        double number;
        int p;
        printf("Enter a number to raise to a power : ");
        scanf("%lf", &number);
        printf("Enter the power to raise %.2lf to : ", number);
        scanf("%d", &p);
        printf("%.2f raised to the power of %d is : ", p);
        double result = power(number, p);
        double mathPow = pow(number, p);
        printf("\n%-20s%-20s\n", "My Function", "Pow() Function");
        printf("%-20.2f%-20.2f\n", result, mathPow);
        return 0;
    }
    // *** Your program goes here ***
    return 0;
} // end main()
```

Comment: Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take [the SO tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please copy-paste the *full* and *complete* output of the compiler (as text!) into the question body.

Comment: Why do you have 2 `int main(void)`? And what is the exact error message?

Comment: And there are a *lot* of errors in your code. Do you come from a Pascal or Delphi background, or some other language where nested functions are allowed? Because in C it's not. Perhaps you should take *many* steps back, get yourself a few beginners books, and start all over from the very beginning?

Comment: This quite-literally looks like you found someone's working example, then slammed it in a C boilerplate, in its entirety, where the "Your program goes here" comment is suspiciously present. Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but sooner or later you're going to have to *write* code; not just find it.

Answer (score -1):

You can't (or at least *shouldn't*) define functions inside functions in C.

```
cc -Wall -Wshadow -Wwrite-strings -Wextra -Wconversion -std=c99 -pedantic -g `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0`   -c -o test.o test.c
test.c:15:41: error: function definition is not allowed here
    double power(double num, int power) {
                                        ^
test.c:36:5: error: function definition is not allowed here
    {
    ^
```

And you have two `main` functions. `main` is the function which gets run by the operating system when the program is run. You only need one.

There's a couple other problems...

```
test.c:41:52: warning: format specifies type 'double' but the argument has type 'int' [-Wformat]
    printf("%.2f raised to the power of %d is : ", p);
            ~~~~                                   ^
            %.2d
test.c:41:42: warning: more '%' conversions than data arguments [-Wformat]
    printf("%.2f raised to the power of %d is : ", p);
```

That `printf` is missing an argument. It should be...

```
printf("%.2f raised to the power of %d is : ", number, p);
```

With those fixes it works fine.

---

You can [DRY](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) up `power` by defining a second function just for positive numbers.

```
double power_positive(double num, int power) {
    int i = 0;
    double result = 1;
    for (i = 0; i < power; i++) {
        result *= num;
    }
    return result;
}

double power(double num, int power) {
    if (power < 0) {
        return 1 / power_positive(num, -power);
    }
    else {
        return power_positive(num, power);
    }
}
```

Comment: The operating system does not call `main`. The program loader initiates execution at the executable’s start address, which is typically at a symbol such as `start`. The code there initializes the C environment and then calls `main`.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I'm sure that difference is irrelevant for OP at his current level of understanding.

Comment: @Geier: The fact they are unable to detect the falsehood now does not mean you have not planted in their mind a false statement that will lead to confusion later in their education. You can easily edit your answer to use solely true statements, with various degrees of detail you choose, such as “`main` is the entry point for your program, and only one `main` routine should be defined.”

Comment: @EricPostpischil That's not my answer.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Welcome to your first day of driver's ed. Move the transmission control lever from P to D. This will remove the parking pawl and allow the fluid coupler to transmit power from the engine to the planetary gears inside the transmission delivering power from the engine to the crankshaft at various gear ratios. Then depress the accelerator pedal which will inform the fuel injection system to supply an increased fuel/air mixture to the cylinders of the engine supplying more power to the transmission, crankshaft, and wheels. Now merge onto the freeway.

Comment: @Schwern: You do not have to give details the reader will not understand. You should, however, not make false statements. It is easy to correct the false statement in your answer. I have given example text above. (Sorry for mixing up users.)